# The Twilio API documentation says that Duration is the number of seconds of the completed call, but the value I am getting seems to be minutes billed

Tags: php, twilio

In this code snippet, $Call_is_from and $Recording match the Twilio call log, but $Duration is much to small to be the # seconds of the completed call:

```
<?php
require_once 'log_file.php';

$Recording = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
$Call_is_from = $_REQUEST['Call_from'];
$Duration = $_REQUEST['Duration'];

log_msg("$Call_is_from\t$Duration\t$Recording");
?>
```

Comment: I haven't used Twilio with PHP so maybe its different, but iirc the Duration parameter is called `CallDuration`, and the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) seems to agree

Comment: That was it! Now instead of it reporting 2, which matches billed minutes, it reports 83, which matches the number of seconds in the call log.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls), to get the duration of a call use the `CallDuration` parameter

```
$Duration = $_REQUEST['CallDuration'];
```